# Adjust PDF with Maxwell Boltzmann (Best Fit)

Tags: statistical-mechanics, simulations, molecular-dynamics

So I got a dataset consisting on different particle velocities.
I've made an histogram (I'm using Octave/Matlab) and I also made the PDF. 
I'm not sure I've made the PDF correctly but these are my results:

```
col1 = input1(:,1); %col1 has the data
hist(col1, 30); % histogram plot
[p,x] = hist(col1, 30); 
plot(x,p/sum(p)); %PDF plot
```

[image]

[image: PDF]

So know I want to adjust the PDF with the Maxwell Bolztmann PDF:

[image]

I've tried plotting that MB PDF with several values of 'a'. 
Does anyone know which values I should assing to 'a'?
Cause the MB PDFs I'm creating are all very small and look like this in comparison with the original values:

[image]

Comment: $a = v_p / \sqrt{2}$, where $v_p$ is the most probable speed.

Comment: Try $a=4.7$ and around.

Comment: None of those are really working. They make the pink lines even flatter.

Comment: Are you sure you are normalizing the histogram properly?

Comment: The thing to understand about the normalization is that the distribution has an integral of 1 by construction. But the integral of your data depends on how many trials you use, right? So *you* have to adjust the height (either scale down your data or scale up the distribution) in addition to finding the right value of the parameter $a$.

Answer (score -1):

As long as the histogram is normalized properly, things tend to work out.

Below, I have an example written in Mathematica. First, I generate data from a Maxwell distribution with $a = \frac{8}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Mathematica has a function,

```
FindDistributionParameters
```

, to fit data to a distribution. Using it with the data, it produces a very good estimate of the parameter $a$, as you see. Plotting the data and the fitted distribution, shows how the most probable speed does lay around 8.

[image]

EDIT:

A possibly helpful note is the distinction over a couple of normalization options for histograms. With the function

```
HistogramList
```

you get access to an array that has the information of the bin delimiters and the bin count for each one. With that we can understand the different normalizations. You obtain the regular un-normalized histogram with

```
Histogram[data, Automatic]
```

The first normalization that you can perform is by dividing each bin-count by the total number of data points. This is denoted as the **"Probability"** option, which guarantees that the sum of the y-axis values adds to 1,

```
Histogram[data, Automatic, "Probability"]
```

Now, in your case, you are interested in matching directly with the probability density function. This leads to the **"PDF"** normalization. It is obtained by taking the un-normalized values and dividing each bin-count by *both* the total number of data points and the bin width. This guarantees that the sum of the y-axis values, multiplied by the bin width, gives 1. This is obtained with

```
Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF"]
```

, which is the option I used above to plot and directly compare with the PDF.

It might help for you to check that this normalization is done properly for your data.